# Does the loopback network inside the docker container shares host network loopback?

Tags: linux, networking, docker, loopback

I recently faced issue with one client application which is running inside a container. This client making network connections to a server residing in the same container over loopback IP 127.0.0.1. The problem here is at some operation the application complains it ran out of ports but checking logs shows that the socket handles at any given time is less than the dynamic ports range in a container.

When I manually changed the IP of localhost to container specific IP in the `/etc/hosts` it started working fine. Please can anybody let me know does the loopback interface of host and container loopback interface are connected at anyway. I believe the network namespace of container will be different from the host. is it applicable to the loopback interface?. Please refer the below for interface details

Container NetworkMode default and driver is bridge:

> Host lo: ip addr show dev lo 1: lo: mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>
> Container lo: ip addr show dev lo 1: lo: mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: I can workout what the question is. Title says about loopback addresses being the same. But then the body discusses port exhastion.

Comment: Hi....Lets take container uses same environment as of host in my case linux distro.I would like know if the  Host loopback ip 127.0.0.1 and Container loopback ip 127.0.0.1 collide on any level while accepting sockets?. As i know container processes are wrapped around by linux namespaces . is there a any exception when it comes to isolating loopback network interface at the container level?.

Comment: Please edit question.

Comment: No, each container has its own loopback device. That's pretty much what the `network_namespaces(7)` manpage says too. @ctrl-alt-delor I find the Q perfectly clear -- the ports are quite obviously NOT a global resource, but scoped to a protocol and address, themselves tied to an interface.

Comment: @Mosvy If words make me think it will say one thing, but then it says the opposite, then it is not clear. It takes too much effort.

Comment: @mosvy, thanks for the clarification